# Express Knex req.query

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, knex.js

`express` and `knex` are beating me a little; I can't make this endpoint work using `req.querys` (response from `express`), even though I made one with `req.params` and it was ok.

---

#### Express:

```js
app.get(`/actor`, async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        // const { gender } = req.query;
        const count = await getActorsByGender(req.query.gender as string);

        console.log({ count });
        res.status(200).send({ quantity: count, });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(200).send({ message: error.sqlMessage || error.message });
    }
});
```

---

#### Knex requisition:

```js
const getActorsByGender = async (gender: string): Promise<any> => {
    try {
        const result = await connection.raw(`
            SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Actor
            WHERE gender = "${gender}"
        `);

        // console.log(`Temos: ${result[0][0].count} ocorrências`);
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

---

This might be because of the `count()`, but I'm not sure. The `knex` part is ok; I can `console.log()` the result.
The `express` part showed a empty object on `insomnia`

[image: Insomnia Page]

Using 'male' as parameter it was expected to return "2" as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sending `male` as [a route/path parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) since you use `http://localhost:3000/actor/male`.

If you want to access it as a query-param, you can leave your code as it is, but you need to change your request-url to `http://localhost:3000/actor?gender=male`

Note that ff you wanted to define `gender` as a route-parameter, you'd need to change your route-handler to `app.get("/actor/:gender")` and access it using `req.params.gender`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `path param` in `insomnia`, not `query param`

If you want to use `query params`, you have to remove `/male` from the URL, and add `query param` `key` and `value` below the URL.

You could also change the URL to `locahost:3000/actor?gender=male`